# Can't delete directory as root

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, root

i've created a directory for a nodejs app some time ago, called blog. The app was started with `forever start app.js`, nothing special.

Now i tried to delete the entire app with folder, i stoped the app and did `rm -rf blog` -> no permissions - all files in that folder are deleted, but not that directory itself.

I tried setting `chown root:root blog -R` and `chmod 777 blog -R` but still no permissions. Another try was to set `chattr -i` but i still don't have the permission to delete that directory.

Any ideas? The server is a vServer with debian 7

Best regards,

Asto

**Update 1:**
the directory is empty, and i am logged in as root. sudo before the commands doesnt change anything. `lsattr blog -Rd` shows `---------------- blog`

the message rm returns is `rm: Entfernen von „blog“ nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung` (No Permissions)

**Update 2:**

`➜  ~  whoami: root`

`lsattr -Rad blog: ---------------- blog`

`➜  blog  ls -l: insgesamt 0`

lsof | grep blog

`zsh       19967           root  cwd       DIR             144,50     4096  109846700 /var/www/clients/client0/web2/blog
lsof      23886           root  cwd       DIR             144,50     4096  109846700 /var/www/clients/client0/web2/blog
grep      23887           root  cwd       DIR             144,50     4096  109846700 /var/www/clients/client0/web2/blog
lsof      23888           root  cwd       DIR             144,50     4096  109846700 /var/www/clients/client0/web2/blog`

`getfacl blog:
zsh: command not found: getfacl`

Comment: Does rm return any error? What's the output of lsattr? Are you logged in as root? Have you checked that you didn't have any hidden files left inside with "ls -a"? If there's any, try lsattr on them.

Comment: Oh, it's a container. Contact your hosting provider for assistance.

Comment: @stoned please see my update 1

Comment: @MichaelHampton what dies that mean? i've created the directory on my own with mkdir und untared items into it (maybe sth changed then?) - oh maybe useful: chroot is installed with ispconfig3

Comment: try `lsattr -Rad`, also post `whoami` and `ls -l` of the "blog" directory. Does `lsof|grep blog` return anything? Do you have the ACL module loaded? If so, what's the output of `getfacl blog`?

Comment: ty very much, through lsof i saw that the parent path to the blog directory was a link... didn't know that. so i got to the original directory where blog was located and with lsattr i could see that the parent directory had chattr +i set ..... removed it and could delete the directory. Thank you for you help. I've learned allot :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the directory was placed in another directory `/var/www/clients/client0/web2` that had chattr +i set. Removed it and could delete the directory `blog`... Thought the original location was another, but it was a link.

Thanks @stoned for the hints!